Closed form for $\int_0^{+\infty} \ln^p(t) \frac{\sin^q(t)}{t^r}dt$
Do you know if there exists a closed form for the integral :
$$I_{p,q,r} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \ln^p(t) \frac{ \sin^q (t)}{t^r} dt$$
where $p$, $q$, $r$ are natural integers such as this integral converges?
For $p = 0$ and $q = r = 1$, it's the well known Dirichlet Integral : $\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{ \sin(t)}{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
For $p = 0$ and $q = r = n$, we can also calculate the integral with elementary techniques :
$$ I_{0, 0, n} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \left( \frac{ \sin(t) }{t} \right)^n dt = \frac{ \pi}{2^n (n-1)!}  \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(n-2k)^{n-1}.$$
And we have also this expression with Eulerian numbers :
$$ I_{0, 0, 2n} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{A(2n-1, n-1)}{(2n-1)!}. $$
For $p = 0$ and random $q$ and $r$ there are also similar formulas but there are also logarithms which appear in the sum.
If now the power of the logarithm is no longer zero, we then obtain expressions which involve Euler's constant as well as Riemann's zeta function. Here are some of these expressions :
\begin{gather*}
I_{1, 1, 1} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{ \ln(t) \sin(t)}{t} dt = - \frac{\gamma \pi}{2} \\
I_{1, 2, 2} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \ln(t) \left( \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \right)^2 dt = - \frac{\pi}{2} (-1 + \gamma + \ln(2) ) \\
I_{1, 3, 1} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \ln(t) \frac{ \sin^3(t)}{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{8}( \ln(3) - 2 \gamma) \\
I_{3, 1, 1} = \int_0^{+ \infty} \ln^3(t) \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt = - \frac{\pi}{8} (8 \zeta(3) + 4 \gamma^3 + \gamma \pi^2 ).
\end{gather*}

a possibly useful transformation is to instead consider $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t)^p (e^{iqt}-1)t^{-r} dt $  then your powers of $\sin$ can be evaluated using just the exponentials from Euler's formula. Here we restrict $r$ to be positive and let $p,q$ range over all possible integers. Another idea is to look at the divergent integrals that result from letting $r$ go negative and see if they have a divergent regularization. All of that hopefully provides additional "tea leaves" to find patterns within.

a (complicated) closed-form expression is at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909143/87355

Thank you, this is the kind of formula i searched !
